# How do I force resize on orientation change?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, responsive-design

I am currently building a responsive layout for a client. Sometimes when I am testing on devices and I test the orientation change, the design will break, or not take into account the new device width.

When starting from either orientation, the layout is working great. It is just during an orientation change that it seems to get stuck on the other width, or again, not take the new width into account.

Is there something I need in the meta viewport tags to force a recheck of the media queries after an orientation change?

Is javascript required? I would prefer a JS free way to do this.

Updating with my media queries:

```
body{
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 830px){

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 

 }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 


}



@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1250px) {

}
```

Comment: show media queries. Are you using `max-width` and `min-width` or are you using `max-device-width` and `min-device-width`

Comment: media queries added to original post

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width` and `min-width` instead of `max-device-width` and `min-device-width`

`max-width` is the width of the viewport/window size

`max-device-width` is the width of the device's screen

For instance Apple products' `max-device-width` remains constant between orientation changes - `max-device-width` acts inconsistently across devices. .

Comment: I was under the impression the two queries I have in there that use min-device-width and max-device-width are specifically targeted at the Apple Ipad mini. All my other queries are indeed just min-width and max width. Are these two queries throwing everything off perhaps?

Comment: Wait a second... don't your media queries allow more than one to go off at the same time? Maybe you should rewrite them so multiple aren't going off at once. For example when I have a width of 1250px arn't all your `min-width` queries going off? Have you written the css so this is not a problem?

Comment: Its a down flowing idea. So I started writing at the base, with no media queries, then I add on to those styles moving up the widths. So yes, at the 1250px level, I am getting everything below it, plus additions I need for that width. I was under the impression this was more of a "mobile first" way of designing, and adding on as I go up the widths.

Comment: Would it be a problem if the `min-width` and the Apple Ipad mini queries were going off at the same time? The Ipad mini queries will also target any other device that falls between that range.

Comment: Yeah good point. Okay so I will try removing them and see if the problem persists.